# Text-Based game in Ruby - Developing a battle system

Tags: ruby

I am currently trying to implement a battle system within a text-based game that I am writing. The player will go from room to room, and sometimes face multiple opponents.

I would like to:

- have the player start off with a max number of hit points, and have that decline as the game progresses
- pre-determine the strength (max hit points) of each opponent
- have the player face many opponents at a time

This is what I have so far, but I am having a lot of difficulty conceptualizing the interaction between the player and the opponents. Also, how would I have the player face multiple opponents in succession?

Any tips would help quite a lot!

Thanks!

GF

Code:

```
class Player 
    attr_accessor :hit_points, :attack_power

    def initialize
        @hit_points = MAX_HIT_POINTS
        @attack_power = rand(2 .. 15)
    end 

    def alive?
        @hit_points > 0 
    end 

    def hurt 
        @hit_points -= amount 
    end 

    def print_status
        puts "*" * 80 
        puts "HP: #{@hit_points}/#{MAX_HIT_POINTS}"
        puts "*" * 80 
    end     
 end 

class Opponent
    attr_accessor :hit_points, :attack_power

    def initialize
        @hit_points = MAX_HIT_POINTS
        @attack_power = rand(1 .. 10)
    end 

    def alive?
        @hit_points > 0 
    end 

    def hurt 
        @hit_points -= amount 
    end 

    def interact(player)
        player_damage_done = 0 
        player_damage_taken = 0 
        while player.alive?
            hurt(player.attack_power)
            player_damage_done += player.attack_power
            break unless alive?
            player.hurt(@attack_power)
            player_damage_taken += @attack_power
        end 

        if player.alive?
            print "You took #{player_damage_taken} damage and dealt #       {player_damage_done} damage, killing your opponent."
            print "\n"
            player.addPoints(player_damage_taken + player_damage_done)
        else 
            print "Your opponent was too powerful and you died."
            death 
        end     
    end 
end
```

Comment: "but I am having a lot of difficulty conceptualizing the interaction between the player and the opponents" - Can you be specific about what issues you are running into?

Comment: Since you seem to have working code and are just having a hard time organizing the design in your head, have you tried https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Thanks Max, I will have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have some kind of environment class to keep track of all your characters. This could be expanded upon to allow movement, etc. Something super simple could look like this:

```
class Environment
  def initialize(player, baddies)
    @player = player
    @baddies = baddies
  end

  def play_game
    @baddies.each do |baddie|
      baddie.interact(@player)
    end
  end
end

baddies = 3.times.map do
  Opponent.new
end
Environment.new(Player.new, baddies).play_game
```

Also, your code as presented won't work. Your `hurt` methods are acting like they accept an `amount` parameter, but you don't ever declare that; you call player.add_points, but don't define that method.. Let me know if you have any other specific questions

Comment: Thank-you for the advice!